# Returning an Integer with RxJava - problem with subscribeOn

Tags: android, mvvm, rx-java, android-livedata

```
@NonNull
private final NoteDao noteDao;

@Inject
public NoteRepository(@NonNull NoteDao noteDao) {
    this.noteDao = noteDao;
}
```

Trying to complete this method which returns an int PK from the Sqlite db.

```
    private void insert(Note note) {

    Log.d(TAG, "saveNote: called.");
    try {
        noteDao.insert(note)
                . map(new Function<Long, Integer>() {
                    @Override
                    public Integer apply(Long aLong) throws Exception {
                        long l = aLong;
                        return (int)l;
                    }
                })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe((new io.reactivex.functions.Consumer<Integer>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Integer integerResource) {
                        // work with integerResource
                        sqCbtId = integerResource;
                    }
                })); new io.reactivex.functions.Consumer<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Throwable error) {
                        // report the error
                    }
                };
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

*** : java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class has no zero argument constructor***

Comment: You are using `androidx.lifecycle.Observer`. Either use `io.reactivex.functions.Consumer` or `io.reactivex.Observer` instead. Also, remove `this`.

Comment: I changed it to this :     .subscribe(<new Observer>);

But the IDE has a red line under both <  > saying its expecting a bracket or expression? I dont know what else to type

Comment: Should put `.subscribe(new Observer<Integer>() {`. Are you familiar with Java syntax?

Comment: I changed it to that and it forced me to implement a method which now comes with its own error:

.subscribe(new Observer<Integer>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

Comment: There are 4 methods but it wouldnt let me paste them all : onSubscribe, onNext, Onerror and onComplete.
The error is "cannot resolve method subscribe on "Anonymous io.reactivex.Observer<<Java.lang.Integer>)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
private void insert(Note note) {

    Log.d(TAG, "saveNote: called.");

    noteDao.insert(note)
            .map(new Function<Long, Integer>() {
                @Override
                public Integer apply(Long aLong) throws Exception {
                    long l = aLong;
                    return (int)l;
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new io.reactivex.functions.Consumer<Integer>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Integer integerResource) {
                    // work with integerResource
                }
            }, new io.reactivex.functions.Consumer<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Throwable error) {
                    // report the error
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Throws a null pointer :(
 W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to  invoke interface method 'io.reactivex.Single  com.example.persistence.dao.NoteDao.insert(com.example.persistenc   e.entity.Note)' on a null object reference
  W/System.err:     at  com.example.ui.activities.NoteActivity.insert(NoteActivity.java:1 42)
    at  com.example.ui.activities.NoteActivity.access$000(NoteActivity.java:43)

Comment: Your `noteDao` is null so have to figure out why and where it should have been initialized.

Comment: I have this at the top of the class: private NoteDao noteDao; It says its never initialized. However if I comment it out using // the noteDao.insert(note) turns red....Thats really confusing to me, how can it not be initialised when Im using it in the method for the insert.

Comment: Are you new to programming or coming from C? You have to initialize objects as Java doesn't have structs. You should perhaps do a tutorial on [Room](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/7-steps-to-room-27a5fe5f99b2).

Comment: Yeah I'm a student. I was simply trying to do an insert and retrieve the id, but the tutorials I watched introduced MVVM, dagger, livedata and a bunch of over complicated stuff that has just confused the life out of me and now im lost. I just want a simple dirty way of doing the insert and getting the id from the activity

Comment: There is an [example repository](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components) you could check out and see how things are done. However, based on your comments, you may want to do basic programming, Java and Android learning before jumping right in the middle of such complicated tasks.